# Show a MapView in a custom dialog?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom dialog with a mapview in the xml...

The dialog shows great without the mapview.

I get this error with the mapview 
MapViews can only be created inside instances of MapActivity.

How can I implement a mapview in a custom dialog?

Here is the simple code

```
public class Upload extends MapActivity{

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.upload_activity);

Button selectPoint = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectPoint);
        selectPoint.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
//showMapDialog();
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Upload.this);
dialog.setTitle("Select Map Point");
dialog.setCancelable(true);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.map_dialog);
dialog.show();
            }
        }); 

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your main activity needs to extend MapActivity.

```
public class HelloGoogleMaps extends MapActivity {
```

Rather than just extending Activity

**EDIT, try this:

```
MapView m = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.YourMapView);
dialog.setContentView(m);
```

Comment: I still get the same error
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5058): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MapViews can only be created inside instances of MapActivity. @MrZander

Comment: At this point, I am not sure... The Dialog needs to have a view passed to it that encompasses the MapView while the MapView is still being controlled by a MapActivity. I am not quite sure how to do this... perhaps a custom view is in need? Sorry I can't be of more help.